# How to render the comment thread in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created a custom content page.tpl.php file and I am trying to display the whole comments section. So far I have been apply to display the beginning of the comments section where the user can enter comments but it is not printing the comment thread. The code I am using to print the comments is

`<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form("comment_node_{$node->type}_form", (object) array('nid' => $node->nid))); ?>`

but this does not display the comment thread, just the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd probably be best to make use of [`comment_node_page_additions()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_node_page_additions/7):

> Build the comment-related elements for node detail pages.

e.g.

```
$rendered = render(comment_node_page_additions($node));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your `page.tpl.php`

```
<?php print render($content['comments']);?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but that does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: That'll only work if comments has been added to the content array, which it won't have been in page.tpl.php

Comment: Sorry, should have qualified that...it won't have been added to page.tpl.php by default. It's entirely possible you're using a theme/module which does add that var (in `hook_preprocess_page()`). The full list of default vars is [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7) if you're interested